# Is there any other available in javascript, Other than $ (dollar) to use as shorthand

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Valid Characters for JavaScript Variable Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names)

I realize that a lot of js frameworks use $ as the short-hand like in jQuery. Is there any other symbol available in javascript, so that I can assign:

```
$ = function(){console.log('working')}
```

Comment: Any letter is acceptable, even the "weird" ones like `é` or `ß`, so you have quite a lot to choose from.  For example `卐 = function(){console.log("hey")}`

Comment: @Deestan - Cool example. But note you can't use *any* letter for a variable name.

Comment: @techfoobar Are you sure?  If so, which letters aren't allowed?  The rule is "any character in the Unicode categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”, “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”, or “Letter number (Nl)”."

Comment: @techfoobar You can't use any *character*, but you *can* use any *letter* (see the linked duplicate for the generous definition of a Unicode "letter").

Comment: @apsillers - Ahh.. ok. I was wondering. Because as is obvious, we can't use things like `.`, `/`, `#`, `.` etc. for variable names. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the dollar sign (`$`) and underscore (`_`), I don't think there are any "basic" characters that aren't taken by basic operations or string delimiters.

**Edit:**

Basically, this means you'll have to give your short-hand a different name if you expect your code to be used in combination with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) / [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

However, like [Deestan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056710/is-there-any-other-available-in-javascript-other-than-dollar-to-use-as-shor#comment19425925_14056710) mentioned in the comments, you can use (pretty much) any ASCII letter as variable name, as long as it isn't taken. Then, it's just a matter of convenience.
Accents like `û` are relatively easy to type. The more elaborate characters could require their ASCII codes to be entered manually, which kind-of defeats the purpose of a shorthand alias.

For example, while impossible to type, this is valid js:

.

Ḣ̶̤̟͍ͦe̱̺̺̮̗̼̖ͫͭ͜͟ͅ ͚͖͙̻̈́̏ċ̨̟̖͙͈̲͇͙̬̲ͩͭ́́́o͎͓̘̭̱̩ͮ͂ͯ̿ͩͨ͂́̚̕m̬͎̜̪͋͛̏̇̊̆̋̉̒͞ę̝͕̯̯̗͋ͩ̿̈́͒̓̾͝s̸͔̜͇̔͊͢ = 'Some text';

.

<sup>(No syntax formatting on it since that breaks the effect)</sup>

Comment: Would the person that downvoted me please explain why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Comment: Your first and third paragraphs appear to completely contradict each other...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Added a slight modification. With "basic" characters I mean letters and / or characters that require no more than 1 keystroke.

Comment: So, ASCII? This is slightly better now.

Answer (score 2):

Most libraries have a noConflict variable too. So, like in jQuery, you could use jQuery.fn instead of $.fn if you wanted.

There's another big library that uses _ and it's called underscore too. Never thought about it too much. But you should always think of collision when you're using common variables in global code.

Comment: :) Seems like someone just went and downvoted every answer... no explanation?

Comment: -1 because you didn't answer the question.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought I had, but reading again yeah, you're right.